# How are ELMo scalar weights obtained in a pretrained ELMo module?

Tags: python-3.x

I am currently using a pretrained ELMo model from tensorflow hub. The question here is, in ELMO task, it is a linear combination (weights) of the hidden states, so how are the pre-trained (weights) obtained in the first place? Another question is how does finetuning work here? Do we tune the LSTM weights or the scalar traininable weights?